# Why don't lookless styles based on HeaderedItemsControl work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So if I create a lookless control that inherits from `ContentControl` then put its style in the `Generic.xaml` file, I am required to add `BasedOn={StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}` to the style in order for it to work. However, when I do the same thing with a lookless control that inherits from `HeaderedItemsControl` I get a runtime exception that says `

> {"Cannot find resource named 'System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedItemsControl'. Resource names are case sensitive."}

This is odd, because it is in that namespace

[image]

Example Code:

Doesn't work

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type myControl}" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}}">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type myContentControl}">
```

Does Work

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type myControl}">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type myContentControl}" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}">
```

My question is, why aren't they handled the same? Is this a bug in the language?

Comment: Your link is referring to Silverlight documentation, are you sure that the reference is in your project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. By convention the default theme style for a WPF control should be defined in a ResourceDictionary called Generic.xaml in a folder called Themes of an assembly specificed by the ThemeInfo attribute of the assembly in which the control type is defined. Please refer to Ian Griffiths' blog for more information about this: https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/02/14/wpfdefaulttemplate

The HeaderedItemsControl has no theme style defined though and that's why you get an exception as you cannot base a Style on another Style that doesn't exists.

The HeaderedItemsControl uses the same default theme style as the ItemsControl, which it inherits from, so this will work:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:myControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

So my suspicion is the reason this is exploding is that HeaderedItemsControl has a null default style on initialization. It actually says this in the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Property Value Type: System.Windows.Style
>
> The Style that is applied to the container element generated for each
>   item. The default is null.

Whereas ContentControl does have a default style, as seen here in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334411(v=vs.95).aspx)

I haven't been able to find this issue documented anywhere and the error is pretty ambiguous. However, I think my conclusion is reasonable.